# Jquery UI ConnectWith not connecting

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am trying to use the [Jquery UI sortable to connect lists](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#connect-lists) of sortable items. Everything seems to be working fine, but I can't seem to be able to get the `connectWith` property to do anything.

I have a fairly simple HTML page:

```
<div id="easy"></div>
<div id="medium"></div>
<div id="hard"></div>
```

and a little bit more JQuery:

```
var puzzles = {
    easy: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
    medium: [1,2,3,4,5,6],
    hard: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
};

for (var i in puzzles) {
    $("#" + i).append("<ul class='" + i + " '>");
    for (var j = 0; j < puzzles[i].length; j++) {
        $("ul." + i).append("<li id='" + i + "_" + j + "' class='" + i + "'>" + (j + 1) + "</li>");
    }
}

$("ul").sortable({
    connectWith: "ul"
}).disableSelection();
```

I have a [demo page on JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R5EKT/).

The lists will sort nicely, but why won't they connect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works with jQuery v1.5.2, but it breaks with jQuery v1.6.1 and above.

more info at jquery UI bugtracker, http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/3739

Comment: Neither the string or array will work. Is there something else that will work? I can just use an old version of jQuery, but it seems like a small issue to change over.